# Two isomorphic reduced group $C^*$-algebras

Tags: oa.operator-algebras, c-star-algebras

Suppose that $C^*_r(G)\cong C^*_r(H)$, can we conclude that $G\cong H$?

Comment: Take two non-isomorphic finite groups $G, H$ with isomorphic group algebras.

Comment: In general the conclusion does not hold, as pointed out by JCA. But some classes of groups have the property you are asking for. Such groups are usually called C*-superrigid.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The simplest counterexample is $G = \mathbb{Z}_2\times \mathbb{Z}_2$ and $H = \mathbb{Z}_4$. These groups are not isomorphic but $C^*(G) \cong \mathbb{C}^4 \cong C^*(H)$.

Comment: Pro Nik weaver,  May I ask you a question:  You proved that calkin algebra has outer automorphisms. Does there exist other open questions concerning $C^*$-algebras which have automorphisms?

Comment: @mathbeginner: nothing comes to mind.